# Proving if $A$ or $B$ are symmetric then $AB$ is symmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove if $A$ or  $B$ are symmetric then $AB$ is symmetric.
>
> Symmetric set definition: $A$ is symmetric if for every $a\in A$ there's $-a\in A$
>
> Product set definition: $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric we're done (seen previously).

Suppose WLOG $A$ is symmetric and $B$ isn't.

So from definition, $\forall a\in A:\exists-a\in A$ and $\exists b\in B:\not\exists-b\in B$.

We'll look at $AB$, from the definition, it has the elements $ab,(-a)b,ba,b(-a)$ from commutative property of multiplication and the definition of sets (they can't have the same element more than once) we have in $AB$ the elements: $ab,-ab$ so from defintion $AB$ is symmetric.

I have a feeling I'm not doing something right, can I just apply the product set's definition to "get" a representation of all the elements in $AB$?

Comment: I just wanted to say "no this is not true" when I realized you ask about sets not matrices. :-)

Comment: Your proof is correct, but I would formulate is as follows. Let $c\in AB$. Then there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $c=ab$. Since $A$ is symmetric $-a\in A$. Hence $-c=(-a)b$ is in $AB$.

Comment: @kuhaku I don't understand your comment. $c\in AB$ was arbitrary and we showed that $-c\in AB$. So $AB$ is symmetric.

Comment: It seems to me that here are to many *symmetric* answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier if you just assume that $A$ is symmetric, without distinguishing
whether $B$ is symmetric or not.

Then from $c \in AB$ is follows that $c = ab$ with some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.
Since $A$ is symmetric, $-a \in A$ and therefore $-c = -(ab) = (-a)b \in AB$.

So $c \in AB$ implies that $-c \in AB$, which shows that $AB$ is symmetric.

Comment: BTW, what if one of the sets is empty? isn't it a counter example?

Comment: @kuhaku: If $A$ or $B$ is empty then $AB$ is empty. And the empty set is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is close to correct but overly complicated.

First, just assume without loss that $A$ is symmetric only (there is no need to assert $B$ is not symmetric).

Now, let $e \in AB$. By definition there exist $a \in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $e = ab$. Since $A$ is symmetric $-a \in A$ and thus $(-a)b \in  AB$. Since $(-a)b = -ab= -e$ we have shown that $AB$ is symmetric.

Comment: BTW, what if one of the sets is empty? isn't it a counter example?

Comment: Why? Then the product is also empty and the empty set is symmetric. For each $a$ in the empty set $-a$ is alos in the empty set. That there is no $a$ at all is not problem. One says this is vacuuosly true.